# Displaying 'copy image' for <p:confirm>

Tags: primefaces

We have a data table [primeface data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gci5.png) with confi
Using primeface 6.1, when clicked on delete icon of last column, works first time (p:confirm button comes once and works perfectly) and again click another row delete icon of last column, showing a 'copy' image. how can we avoid displaying a 'copy image'. [copy image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY7up.png), code is [p:column code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRlXC.png)

Comment: How are you showing and hiding the confirm box?

Comment: @prakash now code is attached in image  p:column code.

Comment: The problem might be with the way you are using `p:confirm`. Take it out from `p:commandLink` and manually show on `oncomplete` of link using `widgetVar` set on `p:confirm`.